# Detect a series of declining values in a postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a series of dates, customer ID's, and integers that updates each week with a new date and integer values for all ID's.

I'd like to be able to write a query that will detect if the most recent three values are in decreasing order, and return TRUE or FALSE, for each ID.

So, for the table:

```
ID | Weekending | Value
1  | 2015-07-15 | 5
2  | 2015-07-15 | 23
1  | 2015-07-08 | 7
2  | 2015-07-08 | 21
1  | 2015-07-01 | 9
2  | 2015-07-01 | 24
```

I'd want a query that would return TRUE for ID:1 because three consecutive values declined, but FALSE for ID:2 because the value increased.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about performance but using the `lag` window function like this should work:

```
select *, 
    case when 
        value < lag(value, 1) over (partition by id order by weekending) 
    and value < lag(value, 2) over (partition by id order by weekending) 
    then 'True' else 'False' end
from t
order by id, weekending desc;
```

This would mark the row `1  | 2015-07-15 | 5` as true, and all other rows as false.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3362c/3)

To only get the last row per id you could do this:

```
select ID, Weekending, Value, decrease 
from (
    select *, 
       case when 
           value < lag(value, 1) over (partition by id order by weekending) 
       and value < lag(value, 2) over (partition by id order by weekending) 
       then 'True' else 'False' end as decrease,
       row_number() over (partition by id order by weekending desc) as r
    from t
) src 
where r = 1;
```

which would give you a result like:

```
ID  Weekending  Value   decrease
1   2015-07-15  5       True
2   2015-07-15  23      False
```

Comment: Ideally, I'd only want to return one row per ID, with the most recent weekending. It seems this will return every value in the the table, no?

Comment: @user882134 Oh, ok. Yes this will process all rows. You could wrap it in an outer query to get only the last rows per id. I've updated my answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can select the relevant records based only on the weekending values (so assuming that all ids have records for every recent week), you could select the values into an array and use array methods to detect whether the values are descending or not:

```
with cte_values as (
  select id,
         array_agg(value order by weekending) value_array
  from   my_table
  where  weekending >= <add something to select the relevant weeks>)
select id
       case
         when value_array[2] < value_array[1] and
              value_array[3] < value_array[2]
         then true
         else false
       end is_ascending
from cte_values
```

Not syntax checked

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) 
id, week,val,val1,val2, val< val1 AND val1 < val2 as decreases
FROM (
 SELECT id,week,val, 
 lag(val,-1,10000) OVER w1 AS val1, 
 lag(val,-2,10001) OVER w1 AS val2 
 FROM TAB 
 WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY week DESC)
 ORDER BY ID,week  DESC) 
AS X
```

This assumes that 10000 and 10001 are "very large values" (true values will always be below that), and that you are interested in strict decreasing sequences.

For example, for the data

```
       id    week        val
        1  2015-07-15      5
        1  2015-07-08      7
        1  2015-07-01      9
        1  2015-06-28    121
        1  2015-06-15      2 
        2  2015-07-15     23
        2  2015-07-08     21
        2  2015-07-01     24
        3  2015-07-15     20
        3  2015-07-08     21
        4  2015-07-15     30
        4  2015-07-08     21
        5  2015-07-08    210
```

this gives

```
   id     week        val     val1     val2   decreases
    1   2015-07-15      5        7        9      t
    2   2015-07-15     23       21       24      f
    3   2015-07-15     20       21    10001      t
    4   2015-07-15     30       21    10001      f
    5   2015-07-08    210    10000    10001      t
```